# Creating a periodic report in Drupal 7 or 8

Tags: views, webforms, log-messages

I have the following use case: users have to report quarterly on their project used an unified form. For example, project 1 is implemented by organization X with contact person John and has to deliver 10 pcs. of A and 15 pcs of B; project 2 is implemented by organization Y with contact person Mary and has to deliver 20 pcs. of A and 3 pcs. of C.

I want to have a report for John and Mary to fill every three months, containing the name of project and submitting person, reference period, item and how many was delivered during the reporting period, as well as accumulated delivery from the project start. Further, I would like to retrieve summary reports on how many items of A. B and C were delivered so far by projects X and Y, and export the information to calculate further stats (i.e. % delivered by project and item, etc.).

The Q2 report for John and Mary should be pre-populated with the information on delivery for Q1 so far, contain fields to add the new performance and sum the new totals for their respective projects. Similarly, in Q3 the reports for both should contain the delivery for Q1+Q2 on their respective projects.

For most of the functionality described, it would be sufficient to use Webform for the reports and Views for accumulating the results; however, I have not found a way to add in a new webform instance representing the Q2 report the data from the Q1 report on the same project.

Could anyone suggest a solution, ideally without programming?

Comment: Forgot to mention the report is to be itemized, that is, every quarter John reports on A and B delivery separately, Mary - on A and C, and the summary I get reflects the progress in delivering A, B and C separately.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a possible approach that may help to address the "reporting" part of your question (not how to pre-populate the webforms, which should really be a separate question I think). It's using "State" names (like Florida, Illinois, etc.) instead of "John, Mary, etc" and "Cities" instead of "A, B, etc". With "City attributes" instead of "pcs".

If I was to implement this in a Drupal site, I'd use either of these "displays":

- **Option 1 - Master detail with nested blocks**

  Have a look at [this example](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.state_breakdown), which shows 1 "block" for each "State", and within each "block" it shows the "Cities" (and one of its attributes) in that "State".
- **Option 2 - Report that filters based on some lookup**

  Have a look at [this example](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.user_distribution_simple?state=IL), which shows only the data about a specific "State", together with all the "Cities" (and one of its attributes) in that "State". To switch to another state, select the desired state from the Parameter form near the top ("IL" is used as the default in this example).

If you wonder "**How did you do that?!?!**" ... then this is the answer: that's really a piece of cake using the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module. And (***without programming***" (unless you would want that instead ...), only using WYSIWYG editing features to either select the data (to build the SQLs) or to create the report that fits your needs to display those data. It also supports creating charts from these data.

Checkout the [Community Documentation](https://drupal.org/node/2041363) for details, and/or the [documentation that comes with the module](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help). The above 2 examples are actually delivered with the module (out-of-the-forena-box), though you probably don't notice that it is even not a typical "Drupal database". It could be such database instead (about data contained in your Webforms), but in this case it's an SQLite (sample) database (it could also have been Oracle, MS SQL, Postgress or any PDO compliant database).

**Disclosure**: I'm a co-maintainer of Forena.

Comment: That was a Wow indeed! Thanks, Pierre, Forena seems very promising and I'll be sure to have a look at it. That seems to answer the report summary part of the question. As to the prefilling the report, this is actually at the core of the help request and comments are welcome.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I keep thinking that you should really "split" your question, eg. by moving the part about pre-populating the webforms to a separated question, in which you might want to link to this one as somehow related to it. Doing so will also help you to select "the" (single) answer that you want to mark as "accepted" (which is what the site rules encourage you to do some day) ... If you have 2 questions, you can mark 1 answer as accepted for each question. Anyway, let me know the outcome after "looking" at forena (you won't regret looking at it, trust me).

Comment: @Kremena : no more feedback? You don't want to create a new question for the part that in this question here that isn't answered yet? Something like a followup question, where appropriate with a link to this question. That way you could also consider marking this answer as "accepted" (similar to what is suggested in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers also)